# How to set values of text box using values of other text boxes

Tags: winforms

I would like to set values to text box, depending on values of text boxes... any idea how to do that in windows form c#? For example i have two text boxes having values and how to fill the product of the value of those text boxes in the another text box automatically? Kindly help me.

Comment: Correct your question title. The question title should be look like a question and your question still uncleared. Please provide more information.

Comment: You take the value of the `textbox` and set the other text box with it. What is not clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is `Control.Leave` event or `Control.KeyPress` or you may also use `Control.TextChanged` as suggested by @LevZ...

**Here is some code for `Control.Leave` Event:**

```
TextBoxFirstNumber.Leave += TextBoxFirstNumber_Leave;
TextBoxSecondNumber.Leave += TextBoxSecondNumber_Leave;

void TextBoxFirstNumber_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBoxFirstNumber.Text != "" && TextBoxSecondNumber.Text != "")
    {
        TextBoxAnswer.Text = int.Parse(TextBoxFirstNumber.Text) * int.Parse(TextBoxSecondNumber.Text);
    }
}

void TextBoxSecondNumber_Leave(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBoxFirstNumber.Text != "" && TextBoxSecondNumber.Text != "")
    {
        TextBoxAnswer.Text = int.Parse(TextBoxFirstNumber.Text) * int.Parse(TextBoxSecondNumber.Text);
    }
}
```

This will fill the `TextBoxAnswer` when the user puts his values in both of the TextBoxes and leaves it...

**Here is some code for `Control.KeyPress` Event:**

```
TextBoxFirstNumber.KeyPress += TextBoxFirstNumber_KeyPress;
TextBoxSecondNumber.KeyPress += TextBoxSecondNumber_KeyPress;

void TextBoxFirstNumber_KeyPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (TextBoxFirstNumber.Text != "" && TextBoxSecondNumber.Text != "")
        {
            TextBoxAnswer.Text = int.Parse(TextBoxFirstNumber.Text) * int.Parse(TextBoxSecondNumber.Text);
        }
    }
}

void TextBoxSecondNumber_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{   
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (TextBoxFirstNumber.Text != "" && TextBoxSecondNumber.Text != "")
        {
            TextBoxAnswer.Text = int.Parse(TextBoxFirstNumber.Text) * int.Parse(TextBoxSecondNumber.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the user enters numbers in both TextBoxes and presses enter on any of them `TextBoxAnswer` will show product...

**Here is some code for `Control.TextChanged` Event:**

```
TextBoxFirstNumber.TextChanged += TextBoxFirstNumber_TextChanged;
TextBoxSecondNumber.TextChanged += TextBoxSecondNumber_TextChanged;

void TextBoxFirstNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBoxFirstNumber.Text != "" && TextBoxSecondNumber.Text != "")
    {
        TextBoxAnswer.Text = int.Parse(TextBoxFirstNumber.Text) * int.Parse(TextBoxSecondNumber.Text);
    }
}

void TextBoxSecondNumber_TextChanged(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBoxFirstNumber.Text != "" && TextBoxSecondNumber.Text != "")
    {
        TextBoxAnswer.Text = int.Parse(TextBoxFirstNumber.Text) * int.Parse(TextBoxSecondNumber.Text);
    }
}
```

Now as the user will enter the numbers for event it will trigger `TextChanged` event and `TextBoxAnswer` will show output.

You may also read [this Official Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for Control Events and use the ones that suits your needs the most.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to update one textbox according to changes in another textbox. For this goal use TextChanged event handler

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    }
```